# CoreData One-To-Many

Tags: cocoa, core-data, uitableview

I have a core data mode that has 1 to many relationship, but i'm struggling to get the value e.g.

Features.h model like this:

```
@interface Features : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * version;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * expires;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * used;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * licenses;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *featureToProducts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *featureToUsers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *featureToDaemons;
@end

@interface Features (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFeatureToUsersObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeFeatureToUsersObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addFeatureToUsers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFeatureToUsers:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

And trying to access it like this:

```
Features *feature = (Features *)[[self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] features];
NSLog(@"featureToUsers = %@", [feature.featureToUsers valueForKey:@"user"]);
```

NSLog shows:

> 2011-09-28 01:06:59.719 Product Name[74092:fb03] featureToUsers = {(
>       "david.wilson" )}

I'm trying to populate a UITableViewCell but I keep getting:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b59a50'

Thanks,
dfox

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm try to get the [feature.featureToUsers valueForKey:@"user"] as string. e.g. "david.wilson" but I keep getting:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b59a50'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back, take a deep breath and look. You have this declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *featureToUsers;
```

And the diagnostic you get is that `__NSCFSet` doesn't understand the `isEqualToString:` message. Where did you get the impression that an `NSSet` should be able to respond to the `isEqualToString:` message? It does't, and it tells you so. `isEqualToString:` is an `NSString` message. You don't say, but I guess, that you want to get some string from your model, and do something with it. Which string? You don't say, but I guess that you have declared that relation to point to another entity named `Users`. You don't say, but I guess (as an aside, you should write better questions by including relevant context) that the `Users` entity has a string attribute of some sort, perhaps `name` or so.

So if you want that string, you need to pull it out from a `Users` instance, perhaps like this:

```
Users *myUSer = ...;  // see below
NSString *myUserName = myUser.name;
if ([myUserName isEqualToString:@"Superman"]) { ... }
```

So key point #1: Core Data lets you manipulate instance of entities, not strings. But entity attributes can be string.

So how are you going to get you `Users` instance? If you write:

```
Users *myUSer = feature.featureToUsers.name;
```

This will not work either. Because the featureToUsers is declared as an `NSSet`, not as a `Users`.

So why is this property, which implements the to-many relation, declared as an NSSet? Because it's a to-many relation, and thus, you need it to be typed as a collection, in order to reach all the related objects.

So key point #2: a to-many relation is declared as a collection (namely an `NSSet`).

So what is inside this collection? Well, the `Users` you want to reach. So you can iterate through every related users for example like:

```
for (Users *aRelatedUser in feature.featureToUsers) {
    NSString *relatedUserName = aRelatedUser.name;
    if ([relatedUserName isEqualToString:@"Superman"]) { ... }
}
```

And now you should be good to go.